# How can I implement binding for an Imbedded Image Resource?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, markup-extensions

1. I am trying to connect the ImageButton Source to a changeable String property in my MainPage. I´m not sure if its the right way to do it. However I am trying to find a way to bind both together using a Binding Expression.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public new  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public String One => "MyNameSpace.Images.Blue.jpg";

        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        } 
   }
}
```

This is the MarkUpExtension I created to give a String as a Resource as I'm using an Embedded Image Resource.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [ContentProperty("ResourceId")]
    public class EmbeddedImage : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string ResourceId { get; set;}
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResourceId))
                return null;
            return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceId);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I was trying to bind the string together in xaml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainPage"
             x:Name = "Main">

    <StackLayout
        BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Main }">
        
       <Image
           
           Source="{local:EmbeddedImage ResourceId = {Binding One}}">
          
       </Image>    
       
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Obviously it doesn't work... I get the error:

> MainPage.xaml(13, 12): [XFC0009] No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ResourceId", or mismatching type between value and property.

Maybe this isn't the way to do it...Is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a string that can be changed, and that string represents an embedded resource (image)

My recommendation is to use [Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters)

First thing, you will have to modify the string property to notify the UI in case the value changes

```
private string _one;
public string One
{
get=>_one; 
set{_one=value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}
}
```

Then you have to create a new class for the converter, here will go your code to transform a string into a ImageSource

```
public class converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string ResourceId=value.ToString(); 
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResourceId))
                return null;
            return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceId);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then, just as any other converter, add it to your application resources in `App.xaml`. This will vary depending on your name class and namespace

```
        <converters:converter x:Key="myConverter"/>
```

And finally, the code for the image

```
<Image Source="{Binding One, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

Also, if your application keeps growing, consider separating the ViewModel to another class

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to write a markup extension.

1. Create an `ImageSource` property and bind to that in the xaml.
2. Set the property using `ImageSource.FromStream` method (and pass the embedded image stream).

Check out the example below.

#### Code Behind

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App5
{
    public partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetImage();
        }

        private int Num = 1;
        private static readonly Assembly Assembly = typeof(MainPage).Assembly;

        private ImageSource _Source;
        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get => _Source;
            set
            {
                _Source = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void SetImage()
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => GetResourceStream($"{Num}.png"));
        }

        private void bChange_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Num = Num == 1 ? 2 : 1;
            SetImage();
        }

        private static Stream GetResourceStream(string filename)
            => Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"App5.{filename}");
    }
}
```

#### XAML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App5.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="This">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Change" Clicked="bChange_OnClicked" />
        <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Source,Source={x:Reference This}}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In order to make the example work, you need to set the project default namespace to `App5` and embed two images with filenames `1.png` and `2.png` in the root folder.